# Swift collectionView hiding layout guidance

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I am looking to create a certain layout with a collection view. Where there are 2 sections to the main viewController, the first being static on the page, and the second being a collectionView which moves over the other when the user scrolls. I want the collectionView to have a limit of how much it cover the static content (it should have a minimum and maximum inset that it can covert). The collectionView has a button which "hangs over" the static section. I have attached some images to describe this further.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

I have thought of a few ways to achieve this, the most promising being a collectionView with a top contentInset of the 'max scrolled down' height. This would show the content underneath and allow the collectionView to be scrolled up and cover it. the button which "hangs over" would be a subview of the collectionView and would also show the rounded corners and drop shadow.

Problems:

- couldn't continue scrolling the collection view whilst also pinning the header to the top

If anyone has any suggestions of how to go about this, please let me know! Thank you.

Comment: You can use [FittedSheets](https://github.com/gordontucker/FittedSheets) Pods, It is very customizable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This could work

Comment: Not sure if this would work with the "hanging button" though